# Connection loss between Meteor and C nopoll application

Tags: c, meteor, ping, ddp

I use nopoll (http://www.aspl.es/nopoll/) for my C application to communicate with Meteor.

Meteor send periodically some `ping` message.
When my application poll websocket, it replies with `pong` message : everything is find.

Next, to avoid polling, I replace it by a callback initialized with `sigaction(SIGIO, ...)`.

Then, when `ping` is received, I send `pong`, but sometimes, server stop sending `ping` and no other message could be exchanged.

Is there any timeout between `ping` and the associated `pong` message.
Is there any mechanism to advertize myself of a connection loss, cause `nopoll_conn_is_ok()` and `nopoll_conn_is ready()` are always `nopoll_true`.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say why Meteor is stopping sending content. However, two points are interesting to be considering your case:

1. You don't have to send a PONG everytime you receive a PING when using noPoll because that's automatically done by noPoll's engine (see nopoll_conn_get_msg() implementation at nopoll_conn.c:2453). Maybe this is causing Meteor to fail.
2. About getting a connection close notification, use nopoll_conn_set_on_close (conn,handler,ptr) to get a notification when the connection is closed. See working examples here: https://dolphin.aspl.es/svn/publico/nopoll/trunk/test/nopoll-regression-client.c

Best Regards,